# extract FASTA sequences sub sets

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a FASTA file with several sequences, like this:

```
> AT1G01250.1 | Symbols: | Integrase-type DNA-binding superfamily protein
MSPQRMKLSSPPVTNNEPTATASAVKSCGGGGKETSSSTTRHPVYHGVRKRRWGKWVSEI
REPRKKSRIWLGSFPVPEMAAKAYDVAAFCLKGRKAQLNFPEEIEDLPRPSTCTPRDIQV
AAAKAANAVKIIKMGDDDVAGIDDGDDFWEGIELPELMMSGGGWSPEPFVAGDDATWLVD
GDLYQYQFMACL

> AT1G03800.1 | Symbols: ERF10, ATERF10 | ERF domain protein 10
MTTEKENVTTAVAVKDGGEKSKEVSDKGVKKRKNVTKALAVNDGGEKSKEVRYRGVRRRP
WGRYAAEIRDPVKKKRVWLGSFNTGEEAARAYDSAAIRFRGSKATTNFPLIGYYGISSAT
PVNNNLSETVSDGNANLPLVGDDGNALASPVNNTLSETARDGTLPSDCHDMLSPGVAEAV
AGFFLDLPEVIALKEELDRVCPDQFESIDMGLTIGPQTAVEEPETSSAVDCKLRMEPDLD
LNASP
```

I want to extract different part of different sequences from a file within a range, like so:

```
AT1G01250   45  102
AT1G03800   65  109
```

I found a Python-based program, [atgc-tools](https://code.google.com/p/atgc-tools/), but it is very picky to take any input file format, so it's not convenient for a large dataset. Can any one suggest a Perl-based solution.?

Comment: what is `45 102` in ouput? how they are derived?

Comment: Do you want to extract a portion of the sequence from record >AT1G01250, from position 45 to position 102?

Comment: Actually I have the accession number and coordinate for every accession number. For example, As Kenosis has mention too, I want to extract the portion of >AT1G01250 from position 45 to position 102.

Comment: cross posted on biostars: http://www.biostars.org/p/82788

Answer (score 0):

This task is pretty easily done with [Biopython](http://biopython.org):

```py
from Bio import SeqIO


records = SeqIO.parse('sequences.fasta', 'fasta')
record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(records)  # dict of records, accessible by accession

ranges_by_accession = {'AT1G01250.1': (45, 102),
                       'AT1G03800.1': (65, 109)}

for accession, (start, end) in ranges_by_accession.items():
    record = record_dict[accession]
    subseq_record = record[start:end]  # For the full record (with header)
    subseq = record.seq[start:end]  # For only the subsequence
    print subseq
```

If you'd prefer Perl, I'd suggest checking out [BioPerl](http://bioperl.org) and its corresponding module [`SeqIO`](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO%3aSeqIO).